# MATLAB substituting for symbolic variables

Tags: matlab, variables, substitution

> > x = sym('x');
> >     P = [1; sin(2*pi*x); cos(2*pi*x); sin(4*pi*x)];

I want to get a matrix Q such that

> > Q = [1; sin(2*pi*1/8); cos(2*pi*1/8); sin(4*pi*1/8)];

That is, how can I substitute x=1/8 into P?

Comment: Hi if the answer solved your problem could you please accept it. This helps SO users to concentrate on older unsolved answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a symbolic substitution.

> Q = subs(P,x,1/8)

Does this work? It should give you a vector.